# Sql Query Assistance. How to properly get items in where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created this abridged sql query.  It needs a level code that is only 2 characters ("GR","PH"...etc) and I need to change the query to allow in one instance to return multiple items.

Here is the code

```
    DECLARE @ALEVL_CODE varchar(5), @test varchar(100)
    SET @ALEVL_CODE = 'GR'
    SET @test = @ALEVL_CODE + ',' + 'PH'

-
                    select ALEVL_CODE  from PMP_Admissions_Letter_Data AD
                    INNER JOIN      PMP_LM_Review LMR
    ON              LMR.PMP_Letter_Data_ID = AD.PMP_Admissions_Letter_Data_ID
    WHERE           LMR.ToPrinter = 1 AND
                    LMR.Extracted = 0 AND 
                    AD.ALEVL_CODE = @ALEVL_CODE                 
                    AND
                    AD.DSCN_MAX_CODE = 'PA'
```

The issue I'm having is with the line `AD.ALEVL_CODE=@ALEVL_CODE`                in the where clause.  I would like to to be something like when `@ALEVL_CODE` is `GR` then do `GR` and `PH` else just do `@ALEVL_CODE`.  Does this make any sense?  Some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            select ALEVL_CODE  from PMP_Admissions_Letter_Data AD
            INNER JOIN      PMP_LM_Review LMR
ON              LMR.PMP_Letter_Data_ID = AD.PMP_Admissions_Letter_Data_ID
WHERE           LMR.ToPrinter = 1 AND
            LMR.Extracted = 0 AND 
            ((@ALEVL_CODE = 'GR' AND AD.ALEVL_CODE in ('GR', 'PH')) 
                OR (@ALEVL_CODE <> 'GR' AND AD.ALEVL_CODE = @ALEVL_CODE))                 
            AND
            AD.DSCN_MAX_CODE = 'PA'
```

Comment: This looks like it could be the solution to the issue.  I just need someone to run the report.  There really isn't any data that would be pulled back.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
    AND (AD.ALEVL_CODE = @ALEVL_CODE
         OR (@ALEVL_CODE='GR' AND AD.ALEVL_CODE = 'PH'))
```

A simplified alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
and case when (@ALEVL_CODE = 'GR') then AD.ALEVL_CODE in ('GR', 'PH') 
         else AD.ALEVL_CODE = @ALEVL_CODE
    end
```

Comment: I've actually tried this I would get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword "IN"